# mysqladmin debug writes out Current locks but PROCESSLIST and INNODB STATUS don't show any

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, mysqladmin

I'm using the 1.1.8 mysql-cacti-templates to gather metrics on MySQL 5.0.77 (CentOS 5.7).

Both the InnoDB Current Lock Waits and InnoDB Lock Structures graphs are charting with Cur[rent] values but there are no Locked Transactions charting in the InnoDB Active/Locked Transactions graph. I also checked `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `SHOW INNODB STATUS` and there are no locks.

However, if I do a `mysqladmin debug` it does print out a long list (dozens) of Current locks to the error log, i.e.:

```
lock: 0x1e6a21b0:

lock: 0x1e7cd750:

lock: 0x1e5bdcb0:

lock: 0x1e839180:

lock: 0x1e821870:

lock: 0x1e737840:

lock: 0x1e6c5590:

lock: 0x1e5b8fa0:

[snip]
```

How can I determine what is causing these locks if they don't show up in a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or a `SHOW INNODB STATUS`? FWIW, I also tried the InnoDB Lock Monitor but it too did not show any locks.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `mysqladmin debug` printing to the console?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA No, it is printing to the error log.

Answer (score 1):

The locks appear to be spurious. Verified bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64140